# Arcgis area solar calculation low value issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, solar-radiation

The output from the arcgis area solar radiation tool for my DEM looks unrealistically low for instantaneous calculation. Here is the example 12PM and 6PM respectively.[image: Here is the result from the run]

The parameters for the run can be found here: 
[image: The parameters for area solar radiation run]

The subset of the dem used here in this example(8mb) can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/843i1r1qyet3fni/example_data.tif?dl=0)

Although the shadow patterns looks realistic but the values are very unrealistic. Ideally the value should be around 1000 w/m2. Any help in interpreting the values of the ArcGIS output?

Comment: projected coordinate system you are using and z value unit?

Comment: and your cell size

Comment: The cell size is 1-meter and the projection is  UTM Zone 11N

Comment: Tried this in [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/ta_lighting_2.html) with the same raster and settings ; it shows Direct Insolation with a range of 945-1080 Wh/M^2, with a mode at ~1070 Wh/M^2. It might be worth editing your question to show the `Topographic` and `Radiation` parameters, in case these have some bearing on the results? Also, did you see the vertical broken line of pixels on the right-hand edge of the raster?

Comment: Your value looks more realistic. I will run it in sage to see if i can replicate this for total radiation. In case of instantaneous radiation the unit would be w/m2, defined by the parameter "moment= [0]". The vertical time shouldn't make any radical difference to the radiation value error i am facing in ArcGIS.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with the requested clarifications that have come out of comments.  Potential answerers do not always have time to read the comments.